# How to prevent SQL injection in emojionearea content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys please help me on sanitization the **emojionearea content** to prevent SQL injection.

I have tried using `$("#id").data("emojioneArea").getText();`  as to get the content on the input without it rendering the HTML tags but it still interprets the html tags such as:

```
  <script>alert("Hi, I am interpreted")</script>
```

My code looks like this: 
HTML

```
<input type="text" id="text_t">
```

JQuery

```
var textContent = $("#text_t").data("emojioneArea").getText();
```

I want to prevent SQL Injection here that no html tags is rendered. But the about getText() function still gets the content that renders the html tags

Comment: SQL Injection should be handled on the server end, not the client.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but your example is an example of XSS , not sql injection

Comment: Ow Yes you are right, but I also needed it for backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the `<` and `>` tags on the client side with a simple regex if you're to prevent users to input html tags.

```
html = html.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

Comment: Let me implement it this way, but it seems like it will solve my issue, thanks